# How to disable Drag from a particular row of a DataGridView in C# and Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm looking for the best way to disable a row of a DataGridView after a successfull Drag&Drop action. 
So, I've already dropped the row and marked it as moved using background color.

Now **I need to disable further Drag&Drop on the same row**. Is this possible without removing the row?

I can de-select a dropped datagridview row but I can't mark it as not "draggable":

```
dgvToolPosition.Rows[dgvToolPosition.SelectedRows[0].Index].Selected = false;
```

Is there any possible way to set a property of the row avoiding the  insertion of the corresponding index on a `List<DataGridViewRowCollection>` of already dropped rows?

Comment: Don't call the DoDragDrop method?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to mark a row as not draggable, otherwise I have to save on a List the row index already dropped to avoid the multiple drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for avoiding the Drag event on a previously dropped row is to check for the unique property of the row that I set on a successfull drop operation (`DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`):

```
// Check if a row in the current selection has a gray background color,
// so it can be skipped on Drag&Drop.
                foreach(DataGridViewRow selectedRow in dgvToolPosition.SelectedRows)
                {
                    if(selectedRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == FCSCoreGlobal.ColorGray) 
                         return;
}
```

I know it's not the best way to do it, but until now it's the best trick I've found. I'm still looking for a `AllowDrag` property on a DataGridViewRow to set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Shot it the dark, but couldn't you just capture the drop event and check if you've moved it to the same row? I did a quick Google search for that event, this is what I came up with :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dragdropeffects(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm already using the `DragDropEffects` on `DragEnter` event handler, but this happens **only after a RowStateChange** on the original DataGridView.